# How can I pass date parameter to MDX where clause and in to subqueries

Tags: subquery, where-clause, mdx

I Have a query, I want to become date parametricly in where clause and in sub query. 
how can I do it?
when i define a set in with clause, I can't use it in where clause  and in sub query.

my main query is :

```
 WITH
SET [countOfProple] As
  filter ([VW Dim Customer Broker Branch].[Customer BK].[Customer BK],[Measures].[Trade Cnt]>0)

  member [measures].[numbers] AS
  count([countOfProple])

select
[measures].[numbers] on 0

    from (
            select 

             {[VW Dim Customer Broker Branch].[Customer BK].[Customer BK]*[VW Dim Customer Broker Branch].[Reception Date].&[2006-09-23T00:00:00]:[VW Dim Customer Broker Branch].[Reception Date].&[2009-08-30T00:00:00]} on 0
             from [DV Present]
        )
     where [Vw Dim Date].[Gregorian Date].&[2006-09-23T00:00:00]:[Vw Dim Date].[Gregorian Date].&[2009-08-30T00:00:00];
```

when I change it in from of below, it will have error:

```
 WITH
SET [countOfProple] As
  filter ([VW Dim Customer Broker Branch].[Customer BK].[Customer BK],[Measures].[Trade Cnt]>0)

SET Date1 AS
[VW Dim Customer Broker Branch].[Reception Date].&[2006-09-23T00:00:00]:[VW Dim Customer Broker Branch].[Reception Date].&[2009-08-16T00:00:00]

SET Date2 AS
[Vw Dim Date].[Gregorian Date].&[2006-09-23T00:00:00]:[Vw Dim Date].[Gregorian Date].&[2009-08-16T00:00:00];

  member [measures].[numbers] AS
  count([countOfProple])

select
[measures].[numbers] on 0

    from (

            select 

             {[VW Dim Customer Broker Branch].[Customer BK].[Customer BK]*Date1} on 0
             from [DV Present]
        )
     where Date2
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume "Date2" is your parameter.

You will need to use one of these functions:

- StrToMember   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146022.aspx
- StrToSet      https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144782.aspx

Then inside either of these functions you need to build up a string to represent the full name, including amersand, of the member or set.

If we hard-code in the string it will looks like one of the following:

For a member parameter:

```
WHERE
  StrToMember('[Vw Dim Date].[Gregorian Date].&[2009-08-30T00:00:00]')
```

For a set parameter:

```
WHERE
  StrToMember('[Vw Dim Date].[Gregorian Date].&[2006-09-23T00:00:00]:[Vw Dim Date].[Gregorian Date].&[2009-08-30T00:00:00]')
```

If using say ssrs and we have a parameter @DtString that can take one of two end date values "2009-08-30" or "2010-08-30" then we could make the set version above dynamic as follows:

```
WHERE
  StrToMember('[Vw Dim Date].[Gregorian Date].&[2006-09-23T00:00:00]:[Vw Dim Date].[Gregorian Date].&[' + @DtString + 'T00:00:00]')
```